# Program calculates square of number incorrectly

Tags: java

The following program is supposed to calculate the square of a number (Different program from previous question) I tried doing this because the previous program used bufferedReader with this in attempt to use scanner. For instance when entering 2 as the number it outputs 1.0 as the squared value of that number.  Any help would be much appreciated! Btw sorry for the spacing i can't get past the first screen unless I space each line 4 times for some reason.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("enter number");
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("the sqare of that number  is "+sqrt(in.nextInt()));
  }

  static double sqrt(double x){
    double result;
    double i=0;
    if(x<0)
      result=-1;
    else{
      while (true){
        if((i*i)>x)
          break;
        i++;
      }
      i=i-1;
      result= (i * i);
      result= (i * i);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: If your function is supposed to find the square of a number, why is it named square root (sqrt)?

Comment: orginal goal was to find square root, but later changed it after reading instructions correctly.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  If so it should be tagged as such.

Comment: Didn't realize such tag existed, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @JasonBraucht [The homework tag is officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: Doh!  Didn't realize the homework tag was deprecated. Thanks for the heads up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Why are you returning `result`? The `i` variable holds the square-root at the end of the `while`-loop, try returning `i`. Then, that first `if`-statement can simply become:</strike>

```
if (x < 0)
    return -1;
```

and you can get rid of `result` completely.

---

I do not fully understand what your goal is here. Your `while`-loop calculates the square-root of `x` - what's the point of that? Why not just `return x*x`? In fact, you don't even need the (rather poorly named) `sqrt` method:

```
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = in.nextInt();
System.out.println("The sqare of that number  is " + (n*n));
in.close();
```

Comment: This does not fix the issue, rather i just inputted 4 as my input and it prints out the square as 4.0

Comment: get rid of every line which uses result?

Comment: This worked when I tried it. Are you trying to determine the *square* or the *square-root*? They are two different things...

Comment: square, so do I remove each line which contains 'result' and place that if statement to where the previous if statement is?

Comment: In that case, how about you delete everything and replace it with `return x*x`.

Comment: that works now, one more thing, in my user created method/function, is there a way to return the method a certain amount of times like 10?

Comment: @user2133068 If you mean return multiple values, not technically, but you can return a `List` or array of values instead.

Comment: how would i return array values?

Comment: you return the entire array

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want in you while loop is `if ( i > x) break;`.  Then the result should be correct because you subtract 1 from i after the while loop - making it equal to x. So, `result = i * i` is the square of x since i == x.